# Взаимодействие с Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Как сделать чтобы при выборе элемента в listview открывался другой listview2?

Например:
Россия - открывается список с городами городов России (Москва,Санкт-Петербург,Омск и т.д.)
Англия - открывается список с городами Англиии

Comment: это для какой платформы и на каком языке вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @pavlofff скорее всего это продолжение серии вопросов по андроиду

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте разместить второй список на новой активити, и переход с помощью startActivuty, либо на одной активити используйте компонент ExpandableListView

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в данном случае лучше использовать фрагменты. В одном фрагменте один листвью, в другом - второй. По выбору в первом фрагменте передаем выбранное значение во второй листвью